# Tips and Tricks about query optimization [SQL Server 2005]

Tags: sql-server-2005, optimization

I am asking this question in stackoverflow because its the right place to ask...

I know its a 
very vast topic to start but some small ones which may be really handy...

It might be useful for young developers like me to know about query optimization..

Some **Tips and Tricks** about **query optimization** in SQL Server 2005..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on questions here

- Avoid datatype precedence (eg always much like for like, including length of varchar etc)

eg

```
...WHERE tinyintcol = @intvalue
 means a conversion of the column and invalidates an index
...WHERE tinyintcol = @tinyintvalue
```

- Avoid functions on columns in WHERE clauses

eg

```
 ...WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, MyCol) > GETDATE()
 should be
 ...WHERE MyCol > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

- Covering indexes
- GUIDs: not clustered indexes

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious place to start if you have a slow query is to make sure it's using an index.

Comment: in management studio, run the command **set showplan_all on** then run your query.  They query will not run, but the execution plan will be dumped.  Look in this output for the word *scan* this is where an index is not being used.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to reduce your total number of joins if possible
- Consider the table sizes used in the query
- Use indexes as they are your friend
- Watch out for the types you are using as keys (int to int is a much easier comparison than  two varchars)
- Avoid using 'Like' queries where possible try to get the value using an equality first

Answer (score 1):

For queries I can add to `gbn`, `recursive` and `smaclell` the followings:

- try to minimize subqueries, joins
- avoid any excessing lockings, saving checkpoints
- use pragmas to set temp table creation in memory
- use pragmas to set synchronous OFF
- use pragmas to disable triggers (if possible)
- embed `INSERT` and `DELETE` queries in transactions
- sometimes `UPDATE` is slower for multiple records than just inserting them again. So advised is to SELECT, DELETE, than programmatically update the records and re-INSERT with the existing keys (watch out for `CASCADE` and `TRIGGERS`)
- check with your sys admins that DB cache should be ON